# Reveal hidden Div stays hidden on submit

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, event-handling

Hello I have a form in a modal. In this form is a submit button. I have results I want to show only when this button is clicked. These results are outside the modal and should be revealed after clicking the submit button. I managed to hide the results but cant seem to reveal it. This is what I got:

```js
function onSubmit(){
    document.getElementById('submitButton').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('revealProgress').style.display = "block";
    return true;
}
```

```css
#revealProgress{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
    <button onclick =" window.location.href = '#close'; deleteData();  getData();;" href="#close" id="submitButton" class="tester2"  > Submit </button>
<div id = "revealProgress">

    <p>Exercise: <strong id="exerciseList"></strong></p></strong></p><br>
    <p>Sets: <strong id="setList"></strong></p></strong></p><br>
    <p>Reps: <strong id="repList"></strong></p></strong></p><br>
    <p>Weight: <strong id="weightList"></strong></p></strong></p><br>
    <p>total: <strong id="totalList"></strong></p></strong></p><br>

    <div id="progress_bar"></div>
</div>
```

Do you see what im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use the JS function at all, that's why nothing happens!

The simplest solution in your case is to replace this:

```
onclick =" window.location.href = '#close'; deleteData();  getData();;"
```

With this:

```
onclick = "onSubmit()"
```

Here's the working snippet after doing so:

```js
function onSubmit(){
    document.getElementById('submitButton').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('revealProgress').style.display = "block";
    return true;
}
```

```css
#revealProgress{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
    <button onclick = "onSubmit()" href="#close" id="submitButton" class="tester2"  > Submit </button>
<div id = "revealProgress">

    <p>Exercise: <strong id="exerciseList"></strong></p></strong></p><br>
    <p>Sets: <strong id="setList"></strong></p></strong></p><br>
    <p>Reps: <strong id="repList"></strong></p></strong></p><br>
    <p>Weight: <strong id="weightList"></strong></p></strong></p><br>
    <p>total: <strong id="totalList"></strong></p></strong></p><br>

    <div id="progress_bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! that works really well as can be seen in the snippet! However i find it odd that its only when i delte the other functions it works...

Comment: @HitE you didn't include those in your JS code that's why I removed them from my solution, but you can still include them altogether like this for example: `onclick = "onSubmit(); window.location.href = '#close'; deleteData();  getData();;"` and it should work!